# Как добавлять товар в корзину, jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Всем привет! Возникла такая проблема: Есть корзина для интернет магазина на jquery, но в нее почему-то всегда добавляется один и тот же товар (самый первый). То есть если я добавляю товар в корзину с индивидуальной страницы товара, то все хорошо, работает как надо. Но у меня есть вывод товаров на главной странице магазина, и вот когда пытаюсь добавить товар именно с главной страницы, то независимо от выбранного товара всегда добавляется один и тот же. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Вывод товара сделан циклом, форма для отправки инф о товаре выглядит так:

```
<form class="row g-3 form_buying_product" action="{% url 'basket_adding' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control number" name="number" min="1" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning submit_btn"
                                 data-product_id="{{ product_img.product.id }}"
                                 data-name="{{ product_img.product.title }}"
                                 data-price="{{ product_img.product.price }}"
         >в корзину</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Вот так добавляется товар в корзину:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $('.form_buying_product');

    function basketUpdating(product_id, nmb, is_delete){
        var data ={};
        data.product_id = product_id;
        data.nmb = nmb;
        var csrf_token = $('.form_buying_product [name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
        data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = csrf_token;

        if (is_delete){
            data['is_delete'] = true
        }

        var url = form.attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.products_total_nmb || data.products_total_nmb == 0){
                    $('#basket_total_nmb').text(data.products_total_nmb)
                    $('.basket-items ul').html("");
                    $.each(data.products, function(k, v){
                        $('.basket-items ul').append('<li>'+v.name+', '+v.nmb+' шт. '+' по '+v.price_per_item+' руб ' +
                      '<a class="delete-item" href="" data-product_id="'+v.id+'">X</a>'+
                        '</li>');
                    });
                }
            }
        })
    }
    form.on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var nmb = $('.number').val();
        var submit_btn = $('.submit_btn');
        var product_id = submit_btn.data('product_id');
        var product_name = submit_btn.data('name');
        var product_price = submit_btn.data('price');

       basketUpdating(product_id, nmb, is_delete=false);
```

Comment: Так у тебя submit_btn, это объект jQuery с набором элементов, при попытке получить данные, он берет их у первого элемента. Замени submit формы на клик по кнопке, ну и соответственно получай данные с конкретной кнопки, по которой совершили клик.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, проблему реши, все заработало :)